# Python: how to convert a str to an array or list of integer

Tags: python, string, list

I have the following `str`

```
tmp=
'794 795 1005 1006 1017 1018 1048 1077 '
```

I want to convert it to a list or an array of integers.

I tried the followings:

```
[int(x) for x in tmp]

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

and

```
map(int, tmp) 

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: Note that the commonly used built-in type is called a *list*, not an array. Arrays do exist in Python, but are a different beast, see the [`array` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html).

Comment: You should `split` the array separated by spaces and then convert into `int`.